# How to remove a contour inside contour in Java OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to run an OCR on a speed sign. I'm getting the contours like below :

```
    static ArrayList<MatOfPoint> getContours(Mat fgMask) {
        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        float threshold = 100.0f;
        Mat cannyOutput = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(fgMask, cannyOutput, threshold, threshold * 3);
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(cannyOutput, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        hierarchy.release();
        return contours;
    }
```

But sometimes, I detect a 0 inside a 0. As you can see here :

[image]

I know that we can use the hierachy mat to do what I want. I just don't understand how to do it in Java.

[Here is a solution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479338/how-to-remove-a-contour-inside-contour-in-python-opencv)

Comment: Did you try using `RETR_EXTERNAL`?

Comment: Yes I tried but if I use `RETR_EXTERNAL` it will stop at the circle and I won't be able to detect the digits.

Comment: Okay then, if you're looking at only the 3 contours you have drawn on your image, you can throw away those for which the parent (the last column of `hierarchy`) is one of the other contours. So if the outer contour of the `0` is `7`, for example, the **parent** of the inner contour of the `0` will be `7`.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `hierarchy` for your example image?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean. Does `0` represents the first contour ?

Comment: I meant the `0` in your image... the second digit of the `50`, whichever contour index that was assigned.

Comment: I'm not sure I've got a good result is this the way to get it correctly ? 
```for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i ++){
                Log.i("Hierarchy", Arrays.toString(hierarchy.get(0, i)));
            } ```

Comment: `hierarchy` is simply a 2-dimensional array. See the last example at the bottom of the page [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Comment: My `hierarchy` looks like this 
```I/Hierarchy: [1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
    [2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0]
    [3.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
    [4.0, 2.0, -1.0, -1.0]
    [5.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1.0]
    [13.0, 4.0, 6.0, -1.0]
    [-1.0, -1.0, 7.0, 5.0]
    [11.0, -1.0, 8.0, 6.0]
    [-1.0, -1.0, 9.0, 7.0]
    [-1.0, -1.0, 10.0, 8.0]
    [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 9.0]
    [-1.0, 7.0, 12.0, 6.0]
    [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 11.0]
    [15.0, 5.0, 14.0, -1.0]
    [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 13.0]
    [16.0, 13.0, -1.0, -1.0]
I/Hierarchy: [-1.0, 15.0, -1.0, -1.0] 
```
I have less on the image because I sort by size

Comment: If you edited that into your question, it would be a lot more readable. Could you also indicate which three contours you've marked in your sample image?

Comment: Well I think I'm going to close this question I manage to delete the inner contour without `hierarchy` because it seems that the inner contour isn't the son of the other contour. I realized that when I looked at your link. Thanks for your time !

Comment: It looks from the hierarchy that the inner contour is either contour 10, 12 or 14. (At a guess, I'd say 10, but I can't be sure without more information.) Are you saying that it's none of those?